# Neo4j Determine nearest node which has less then two children

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

can somebody help me solve my problem? Assume that I have a binary tree where I should append child by following rules:

- Given random node within tree
- Node should be apended as a "child" of given node in nearest available place (as a direct child of node which has leess then 2 children)

I got stuck with cypher query of deternine actual parent node (Working not correctly).

What I have for now is

```
start n=node({0}) 
match child-[B_PARENT]->n 
OPTIONAL MATCH child<-[r:B_PARENT]-() 
WITH count(r) as c, child WHERE c < 2 
return child ORDER BY id(child) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: maybe you can create and share a small sample dataset using http://console.neo4j.org ?

Answer (score 0):

```
START n=node({0})
MATCH (node1)-[r:B_PARENT]-(node2) 
WHERE (node1 <> node2 AND node1 = n AND count(r)<2) OR (node1 <> node2 AND node1 <> n AND count(r)<3)
RETURN node1 ORDER BY id(node1) LIMIT 1
```

The logic here is assuming the given node is in binary tree, it will at max have 3 relationships. If the root is a root node it will have max 2 relationships.

```
(node1 <> node2 AND node1 = n AND count(r)<2)  // will work only for root node

(node1 <> node2 AND node1 <> n AND count(r)<3) //will work for other nodes in the tree
```

So the above query should return the node with an open place for a child having the least id.